# How to I configure Mail.app to keep the oldest message on top?

Tags: mail.app

How do I configure Mail.app to keep the oldest message on top?

I regularly have a need to change the sorting of my inbox from "Date" to "From" or "Flag".  When I change the sorting back to "Date", the newest messages are placed on top.  This is, of course, easy to fix; but, it is terribly annoying to have to go through this two-step process every time.  Is there a way to configure Mail.app so that it won't change this setting whenever I change the primary "sort by" field?

(I have Mail.app version 9.3 3124)

Comment: Did you tried to check View -> Sort By -> Ascending?

Comment: Yes.  The specific menu item is "Oldest Message On Top" as opposed to "Ascending".  The problem is that the setting won't "stick". When ever I change the "Primary" sort by criterion ("Date", "From", "Flags", etc.) the "secondary" sort by criterion gets re-set to "Newest On Top"